# Creating custom alerts by list column value Sharepoint NOT working

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, caml

I've been trying to set an alert that sends email whenever a user changes a value of the multi-select to different set of values only when they select a certain column with a certain value in SharePoint List. I've managed to create the alerts with caml query however, I am getting alerts on any changes made to the list.

here is my query -

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <Or>
      <Contains><FieldRef Name='CustomColumn_x0020_One'/><Value Type='MultiChoice'>My test value 1</Value></Contains>
      <Contains><FieldRef Name='CustomColumn_x0020_Two'/><Value Type='MultiChoice'>My test value 2</Value></Contains>
    </Or>
</Where>
</Query>
```

for multiple columns and values that I want for the alert to trigger and

```
<Query>
<Where>
      <Contains><FieldRef Name='CustomColumn_x0020_One'/><Value Type='MultiChoice'>My test value 1</Value></Contains>
</Where>
</Query>
```

for single item.

After that, I would do something like,

```
 AlertCreationInformation myNewAlert = new AlertCreationInformation();
 myNewAlert.List = tmpList;

 // query has either one of the caml queries I listed above.
 myNewAlert.Filter = query.ToString();
 myNewAlert.AlertFrequency = AlertFrequency.Immediate;
 myNewAlert.AlertType = AlertType.List;
 myNewAlert.AlwaysNotify = false;
 myNewAlert.DeliveryChannels = AlertDeliveryChannel.Email;
 myNewAlert.EventType = AlertEventType.All;
 myNewAlert.Status = AlertStatus.On;
 myNewAlert.Title = "test";
 myNewAlert.User = currentUser;
 var newAlertGuid = currentUser.Alerts.Add(myNewAlert);
 currentUser.Update();
```

I know that you can create workflows to achieve what I am trying to do, but to do so programmatically, I was not able to find much of reliable documentation nor Event listeners.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try:

1) Replace "Where" elements with "Query". Alert filters do not accept Where elements.
2) Replace "MultiChoice" with "Text".

```
<Query>
    <Or>
      <Contains><FieldRef Name='CustomColumn_x0020_One'/><Value Type='Text'>My test value 1</Value></Contains>
      <Contains><FieldRef Name='CustomColumn_x0020_Two'/><Value Type='Text'>My test value 2</Value></Contains>
    </Or>
</Query>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I will try that as soon as possible. One question though, for the AlertEventType property in the alert object, does Sharepoint require us to set that to be a "Custom" value for the caml query in filter to work?

Comment: I used List. I'm not sure what Custom does.